# Wanted but not invoked: <Capturing argument>Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-cloud-contract

I am using spring boot, maven, junit4, the test code is as below, when I run this test, I always get the following error:

> Wanted but not invoked:
> onSubscriptionEventListener.handleSubscriptionEvent(
>  );
> -> at com.sap.ngom.urm.contract.consumer.VerifySubscriptionKafkaEventContractTest.handle_subscription_deleted_event(VerifySubscriptionKafkaEventContractTest.java:142)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
>
> Wanted but not invoked:
> onSubscriptionEventListener.handleSubscriptionEvent(
>  );
> -> at com.sap.ngom.urm.contract.consumer.VerifySubscriptionKafkaEventContractTest.handle_subscription_deleted_event(VerifySubscriptionKafkaEventContractTest.java:142)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DummyApplication.class},
        properties = {"stubrunner.kafka.enabled=true","stubrunner.stream.enabled=false","spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}"})
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.xxx.contracts:+:stubs"}, consumerName = "urm")
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = {xxx_TOPIC})
@ActiveProfiles({"contracttest"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class VerifyKafkaEventContractTest {

    @Autowired
    StubTrigger stubTrigger;

    @SpyBean
    OnSubscriptionEventListener onSubscriptionEventListener;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<SubscriptionEvent> subscriptionArgumentCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(onSubscriptionEventListener).handleSubscriptionEvent(any());
 

    }

    @Test
    public void handle_subscription_deleted_event() {

        stubTrigger.trigger("kafka-subscription-deletion-urm");

 verify(onSubscriptionEventListener).handleSubscriptionEvent(subscriptionArgumentCaptor.capture());
            }
     }
```

Could this be a bug of the @SpyBean?

Comment: Please show us all annotations on the test class. My guess: you overwrite your mocks with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: @Lesiak , have show all the annotations . the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); can be removed, this line do not impact the test result. 
The test always failed with the same reason

Answer (score 0):

My service have other listener which use the spring cloud stream to consume the rabbitmq event. So I implement the listener with spring cloud stream instead of using the @kafkaListener. Then the contract test works.
Assume this is a bug when using the spring cloud stream together with the kafka